# consume SOAP Response always null Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap

I already create the SOAP Client to consume the SOAP Webservices server.

1. Here is my web services class that called the SOAP Server

   ```
   public class SOAPConnector extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

       public HostCustomerResponse getHost() {

           String CData;

           String DEBIT_ACCTNO = "800000123800";

           HostCustomer request = new HostCustomer();
           Input input = new Input();
           input.setCorpID("IDTITOUAT123");
           input.setRequestID("1705547561");
           input.setServiceCode("ACCOUNT_BALANCE");
           input.setTokenAuth("c29c1704547fa0e2ceeabc8099bb7a4510dc0cf535d332fc75faeadcce14510b");
           CData = "<![CDATA["+
                   "<balanceRequest>"+
                   "<balance>"+
                       "<accountNo>"+DEBIT_ACCTNO+"</accountNo>"+
                   "</balance>"+
               "</balanceRequest>"+
               "]]>";

           input.setTxnData(CData);
           input.setTxnRequestDateTime("20180904144630");

           request.setInput(input);

           HostCustomerResponse response = (HostCustomerResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(request, new SoapActionCallback("http://pguat2.cimbniaga.co.id:8004/PrismaGateway/services/HostCustomer"));        
           System.out.println(response.getOutput().getTxnData());
           return response;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Other class separated

   ```
   public class Config {

       @Bean
       public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
           Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
           marshaller.setContextPaths("prismagateway_service","prismagateway_param");
           return marshaller;
       }


       @Bean
       public SOAPConnector soapConnector(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
           SOAPConnector client = new SOAPConnector();
           client.setDefaultUri("http://pguat2.cimbniaga.co.id:8004/PrismaGateway/services/HostCustomer");
           client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
           client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
           return client;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Package
   [class generated from wsdl file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpRcb.jpg)
4. **Wsdl Class**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://10.25.112.133" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://10.25.112.133" xmlns:intf="http://10.25.112.133" xmlns:tns1="java:prismagateway.service.HostCustomer" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!-- WSDL created by PrismaGateway -->
 <wsdl:types>
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://10.25.112.133" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <import namespace="java:prismagateway.service.HostCustomer"/>
   <element name="HostCustomer">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="input" type="tns1:Input"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
   <element name="HostCustomerResponse">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="output" type="tns1:Output"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
  </schema>
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="java:prismagateway.service.HostCustomer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <complexType name="Input">
    <sequence>
     <element name="tokenAuth" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="txnData" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="serviceCode" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="corpID" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="requestID" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="txnRequestDateTime" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="Output">
    <sequence>
     <element name="bankReffNo" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="statusCode" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="statusMsg" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="txnResponseDateTime" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="txnData" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
  </schema>
 </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message name="HostCustomerResponse">
      <wsdl:part element="impl:HostCustomerResponse" name="parameters"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="HostCustomerRequest">
      <wsdl:part element="impl:HostCustomer" name="parameters"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:portType name="HostCustomer">
      <wsdl:operation name="HostCustomer">
         <wsdl:input message="impl:HostCustomerRequest" name="HostCustomerRequest"/>
         <wsdl:output message="impl:HostCustomerResponse" name="HostCustomerResponse"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="HostCustomerSoapBinding" type="impl:HostCustomer">
      <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="HostCustomer">
         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
         <wsdl:input name="HostCustomerRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output name="HostCustomerResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="HostCustomer">
      <wsdl:port binding="impl:HostCustomerSoapBinding" name="HostCustomer">
         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://pguat2.cimbniaga.co.id:8004/PrismaGateway/services/HostCustomer"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

2. This is the console response
   **The Problem is I already get Soap Response in Console logging.level.org.springframework.ws=TRACE, But always Null when I print in // System.out.println(response.getOutput().getTxnData());// SOAPConnectorClass above. How it can be?**

```html
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.1.RELEASE)

2018-09-06 11:23:19.262  INFO 10340 --- [           main] s.SpringBootSoapClientApplication        : Starting SpringBootSoapClientApplication on DESKTOP-7CF3AR1 with PID 10340 (D:\SpringWorkspace\spring-boot-soap\target\classes started by KPT-IT-EZRA in D:\SpringWorkspace\spring-boot-soap)
2018-09-06 11:23:19.268  INFO 10340 --- [           main] s.SpringBootSoapClientApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-09-06 11:23:19.321  INFO 10340 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a4927d6: startup date [Thu Sep 06 11:23:19 ICT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-06 11:23:20.248  INFO 10340 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5f57ab1c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-09-06 11:23:20.284  INFO 10340 --- [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2018-09-06 11:23:20.751  INFO 10340 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9090 (http)
2018-09-06 11:23:20.764  INFO 10340 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2018-09-06 11:23:20.766  INFO 10340 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.5
2018-09-06 11:23:20.872  INFO 10340 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-09-06 11:23:20.873  INFO 10340 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1556 ms
2018-09-06 11:23:21.068  INFO 10340 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-09-06 11:23:21.070  INFO 10340 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'messageDispatcherServlet' to [/services/*]
2018-09-06 11:23:21.074  INFO 10340 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-06 11:23:21.075  INFO 10340 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-06 11:23:21.075  INFO 10340 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-06 11:23:21.075  INFO 10340 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-06 11:26:04.810  INFO 10340 --- [           main] o.s.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller             : Creating JAXBContext with context path [_133._112._25._10:prismagateway_service]
2018-09-06 11:27:14.463  INFO 10340 --- [           main] o.s.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory  : Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
2018-09-06 11:27:14.471 DEBUG 10340 --- [           main] o.s.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory  : Using MessageFactory class [com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl]
2018-09-06 11:27:59.795  INFO 10340 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a4927d6: startup date [Thu Sep 06 11:23:19 ICT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-06 11:28:00.066  INFO 10340 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-09-06 11:28:00.069  INFO 10340 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-09-06 11:28:00.276  INFO 10340 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-09-06 11:28:00.276  INFO 10340 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-09-06 11:28:00.558  INFO 10340 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-09-06 11:28:01.090 DEBUG 10340 --- [           main] yloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping : Looking for endpoints in application context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a4927d6: startup date [Thu Sep 06 11:23:19 ICT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-06 11:28:01.138 DEBUG 10340 --- [           main] oapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping : Looking for endpoints in application context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a4927d6: startup date [Thu Sep 06 11:23:19 ICT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-06 11:28:01.205 DEBUG 10340 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.e.a.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter : No MethodArgumentResolvers set, using defaults: [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.dom.DomPayloadMethodProcessor@124ac145, org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.MessageContextMethodArgumentResolver@2def7a7a, org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.SourcePayloadMethodProcessor@24e83d19, org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.XPathParamMethodArgumentResolver@5c080ef3, org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.adapter.method.SoapMethodArgumentResolver@188cbcde, org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.adapter.method.SoapHeaderElementMethodArgumentResolver@4ee6291f, org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor@2b03d52f, org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.JaxbElementPayloadMethodProcessor@37e0292a, org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.StaxPayloadMethodArgumentResolver@4af70944]
2018-09-06 11:28:01.210 DEBUG 10340 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.e.a.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter : No MethodReturnValueHandlers set, using defaults: [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.dom.DomPayloadMethodProcessor@35267fd4, org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.SourcePayloadMethodProcessor@397ef2, org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor@36a6bea6, org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.JaxbElementPayloadMethodProcessor@44e93c1f]
2018-09-06 11:28:01.748  INFO 10340 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-09-06 11:28:44.850  INFO 10340 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 9090 (http)
2018-09-06 11:28:56.622  INFO 10340 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5f7989fa: startup date [Thu Sep 06 11:28:56 ICT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-06 11:29:06.116  INFO 10340 --- [           main] o.s.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller             : Creating JAXBContext with context path [_133._112._25._10:prismagateway_service]
2018-09-06 11:29:16.561  INFO 10340 --- [           main] o.s.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory  : Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
2018-09-06 11:29:16.564 DEBUG 10340 --- [           main] o.s.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory  : Using MessageFactory class [com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl]
2018-09-06 11:29:24.733 DEBUG 10340 --- [           main] o.s.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate    : Opening [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnection@5f0f9947] to [http://pguat2.cimbniaga.co.id:8004/PrismaGateway/services/HostCustomer]
2018-09-06 11:29:25.202 TRACE 10340 --- [           main] o.s.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent        : Sent request [<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns3:HostCustomer xmlns:ns2="java:prismagateway.service.HostCustomer" xmlns:ns3="http://10.25.112.133"><ns3:input><ns2:tokenAuth>c29c1704547fa0e2ceeabc8099bb7a4510dc0cf535d332fc75faeadcce14510b</ns2:tokenAuth><ns2:txnData>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;balanceRequest&gt;&lt;balance&gt;&lt;accountNo&gt;800000123800&lt;/accountNo&gt;&lt;/balance&gt;&lt;/balanceRequest&gt;]]&gt;</ns2:txnData><ns2:serviceCode>ACCOUNT_BALANCE</ns2:serviceCode><ns2:corpID>IDTITOUAT123</ns2:corpID><ns2:requestID>1705547561</ns2:requestID><ns2:txnRequestDateTime>20180904144630</ns2:txnRequestDateTime></ns3:input></ns3:HostCustomer></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>]
2018-09-06 11:29:35.873 TRACE 10340 --- [           main] o.s.ws.client.MessageTracing.received    : Received response [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><HostCustomerResponse xmlns="http://10.25.112.133"><ns1:output xmlns:ns1="http://10.25.136.152" xmlns:ns2="java:prismagateway.service.HostCustomer" xsi:type="ns2:Output"><ns2:bankReffNo xsi:nil="true"/><ns2:statusCode>008</ns2:statusCode><ns2:statusMsg>Request message is expired</ns2:statusMsg><ns2:txnResponseDateTime>20180906112726</ns2:txnResponseDateTime><ns2:txnData>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;balanceRequest&gt;&lt;balance&gt;&lt;accountNo&gt;800000123800&lt;/accountNo&gt;&lt;/balance&gt;&lt;/balanceRequest&gt;]]&gt;</ns2:txnData></ns1:output></HostCustomerResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>] for request [<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns3:HostCustomer xmlns:ns2="java:prismagateway.service.HostCustomer" xmlns:ns3="http://10.25.112.133"><ns3:input><ns2:tokenAuth>c29c1704547fa0e2ceeabc8099bb7a4510dc0cf535d332fc75faeadcce14510b</ns2:tokenAuth><ns2:txnData>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;balanceRequest&gt;&lt;balance&gt;&lt;accountNo&gt;800000123800&lt;/accountNo&gt;&lt;/balance&gt;&lt;/balanceRequest&gt;]]&gt;</ns2:txnData><ns2:serviceCode>ACCOUNT_BALANCE</ns2:serviceCode><ns2:corpID>IDTITOUAT123</ns2:corpID><ns2:requestID>1705547561</ns2:requestID><ns2:txnRequestDateTime>20180904144630</ns2:txnRequestDateTime></ns3:input></ns3:HostCustomer></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>]
2018-09-06 11:39:21.690  INFO 10340 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-09-06 11:39:21.919 ERROR 10340 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:803) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:771) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
 at springbootsoapclient.SpringBootSoapClientApplication.main(SpringBootSoapClientApplication.java:23) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at springbootsoapclient.SpringBootSoapClientApplication.lambda$0(SpringBootSoapClientApplication.java:81) [classes/:na]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
 ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Comment: i already edit my post. you can see now

Comment: And have you checked line 51 in your SoapConnector class? Which line is it?

Comment: i already check it, and thats not the problem. if i convert it to string and print the result is still "null"

Comment: Can you check the response you got from the service call. If it has error messages, JAXB will not be able to match it to any of your classes.

Comment: how i can check the response true ? i agree to your opinion, i assume this cause the response not match with my class that generated from wsdl file.

Comment: You can check if the response body fields map to any of your JAXB annotated classes. I suggest you share full response and wsdl

Comment: i already updates the post. help me please...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like below line causing the issue.

```
System.out.println(response.getOutput().getTxnData());
```

So please change it like this

```
if(response!=null && response.getOutput()!=null){
   System.out.println(response.getOutput().getTxnData());
}
```

Comment: already work, but still null response. how i can get the data ?

Comment: Please share full response you are getting in log file.